# if statement in scrapy yield

Tags: python, scrapy

How can I add an if statement in the yield{} section see that part for Fight_Url below at the bottom of the code

basically if the result part says next I need it to just not look for the url

```html
import pandas as pd
import scrapy


urls_csv = pd.read_csv('fighters.csv')
urls_list = urls_csv.url.to_list()


class FightersDetailsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fight_urls"

    def start_requests(self):
        links = []

        for link in urls_list:
            links.append(link)

        for url in links:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):

        for fight_url in response.xpath('//*[@class="b-fight-details__table-body"]//tr')[1:]:
            yield {
                'Url': response.request.url,
                'Result': fight_url.xpath('.//td[1]/p/a/i/i/text()').extract_first().strip(),
                'First_Name': fight_url.xpath('.//td[2]/p[1]/a/text()').extract_first().strip().split()[0],
                'Last_Name': fight_url.xpath('.//td[2]/p[1]/a/text()').extract_first().strip().split()[1],
                'Opponent_First': fight_url.xpath('.//td[2]/p[2]/a/text()').extract_first().strip().split()[0],
                'Opponent_Last': fight_url.xpath('.//td[2]/p[2]/a/text()').extract_first().strip().split()[1],
                'Opponent_URL': fight_url.xpath('.//td[2]/p[2]/a/@href').extract_first(),
                'Fight_Url':
                        if fight_url.xpath('.//td[1]/p/a/i/i/text()').extract_first().strip() == "next":
                            None
                        else:
                            fight_url.xpath('.//@href').extract_first(),
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to modify the `if-else` syntax slightly:

```
        for fight_url in response.xpath('//*[@class="b-fight-details__table-body"]//tr')[1:]:
            yield {
                'Url': response.request.url,
                'Result': fight_url.xpath('.//td[1]/p/a/i/i/text()').extract_first().strip(),
                'First_Name': fight_url.xpath('.//td[2]/p[1]/a/text()').extract_first().strip().split()[0],
                'Last_Name': fight_url.xpath('.//td[2]/p[1]/a/text()').extract_first().strip().split()[1],
                'Opponent_First': fight_url.xpath('.//td[2]/p[2]/a/text()').extract_first().strip().split()[0],
                'Opponent_Last': fight_url.xpath('.//td[2]/p[2]/a/text()').extract_first().strip().split()[1],
                'Opponent_URL': fight_url.xpath('.//td[2]/p[2]/a/@href').extract_first(),
                'Fight_Url':
                        None if fight_url.xpath('.//td[1]/p/a/i/i/text()').extract_first().strip() == "next"
                        else fight_url.xpath('.//@href').extract_first(),
            }
```